# Python avoid dividing by zero in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, divide-by-zero

Apologies that this has been asked before, but I cannot get those solutions to work for me (am native MATLAB user coming to Python).

I have a dataframe where I am taking the row-wise mean of the first 7 columns of one df and dividing it by another. However, there are many zeros in this dataset and I want to replace the zero divion errors with zeros (as that's meaningful to me) instead of the naturally returned nan (as I'm implementing it).

My code so far:

```
col_ind = list(range(0,7))
df.iloc[:,col_ind].mean(axis=1)/other.iloc[:,col_ind].mean(axis=1)
```

Here, if other = 0, it returns nan, but if df = 0 it returns 0. I have tried a lot of proposed solutions but none seem to register. For instance:

```
def foo(x,y):
    try:
        return x/y
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0

foo(df.iloc[:,col_ind].mean(axis1),other.iloc[:,col_ind].mean(axis=1))
```

However this returns the same values without using the defined foo. I'm suspecting this is because I am operating on series rather than single values, but I'm not sure nor how to fix it. There are also actual nans in these dataframes as well. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow (and to Python) can you provide us a little bit more of your code? For instance,  what is your Dataframe `df`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use **np.where** to conditionally do this as a vectorised calc.

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.concatenate([np.random.randint(1,10, (10,7)), np.random.randint(0,3,(10,1))], axis=1),
            columns=[f"col_{i}" for i in range(7)]+["div"])

np.where(df["div"].gt(0), (df.loc[:,[c for c in df.columns if "col" in c]].mean(axis=1) / df["div"]), 0)
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to have worked. I'm not entirely sure what .gt is appended on the .where.

Returning this to my example, df["div"] is 'other' and .gt(0) returns a true/false vector where any element of other that is a 0 returns a false. Then, the statement carries out normal division where other != 0, and returns 0 otherwise. I was playing around with np.where previously but am not sure why this one works. For those interested, my corrected code:
`np.where(other.iloc[:,col_ind].mean(axis=1).gt(0), (df.iloc[:,col_ind].mean(axis=1) / other.iloc[:,col_ind].mean(axis=1)), 0)`

Comment: I probably should have used `.ne(0)` to remove assumption the divisor is positive

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear which version you're using and I don't know if the behavior is version-dependent, but in Python 3.8.5 / Pandas 1.2.4, a 0 / 0 in a dataframe/series will evaluate to NaN, while a non-zero / 0 will evaluate to inf. Neither will raise an error, so a try/except wouldn't have anything to catch.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 1, 2], 'b': [0, 0, 2]})
>>> x

   a  b
0  0  0
1  1  0
2  2  2

>>> x.a / x.b
0    NaN
1    inf
2    1.0
dtype: float64
```

You can replace NaN values in a pandas DataFrame or Series with the `fillna()` method, and you can replace inf using a standard `replace()`:

```
>>> (x.a / x.b).replace(np.inf, np.nan)
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    1.0
dtype: float64

>>> (x.a / x.b).replace(np.inf, np.nan).fillna(0)
0    0.0
1    0.0
2    1.0
dtype: float64
```

(Note: A negative value divided by zero will evaluate to -inf, which would need to be replaced separately.)

Comment: You are correct, I was misreading what my commands were returning, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace `nan` after the calculation using [df.fillna(0)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

Comment: The dataset already has actual nan values that need to be left in unfortunately